# Is CloudFront configurations be used to handle what Micro-frontend applications?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Amazon CloudFront has capability to configure path to multiple S3 assets which can be like react application maintained by multiple teams. If this is the case, why would teams using AWS ever use micro frontend when CloudFront can do it.

I have a single requirement, but I am not sure which is best suited. I know single SPA (Single Page Application) can help here, but I have knowledge gap what additional benefits we will get. We are using authentication as well. How to use SPA as Micro-frontend work with Amazon CloudFront?

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> After a successful login, the parent application **retrieves the child
> applications** **from CloudFront** and renders them inside the parent
> application.

Source https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/micro-frontend-architectures-on-aws .

Yes, you can make micro-front-end with Amazon CloudFront.

Comment: I mean can it be done with just using routing in cloudfront but not using any module federation.